# How to convert CSV data into floating point numbers with SSIS

Tags: csv, ssis, floating-point, ssis-2012, decimal-point

I am stuck with a CSV flat file imported into a SSIS data flow. There is a "price" column listing prices with 2 values after the decimal dot such as 13.15, 8.20, 125,60 etc. 
How can I transform this to a floating or decimal number? When I select Data type as Decimal, Money or Floating I Always get in return an integer (1315,820,12560 etc...).
Thanks
Rick

Comment: Hi Rick, maybe this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251143/ssis-derived-column-from-csv-cast-string-to-float

Comment: Hi Benzi. Thanks I solved. It was the regional settings on my PC which were not set to "." for decimals. Now it is fine :-)

Comment: Great, glad to hear.